# Django postgis point is in polygon or on boundary

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I have a `PolygonField` `poly` in my model.

For a given point I want to filter all items that either lie within polygon, or lie on its boundary or the smallest distance between the point and polygon is `x`.

`.filter(poly__contains=point)` checks only first. What about other two conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Try from these:

Distance: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance-lookups

On boundary and within: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#overlaps

Use .filter(Q()|Q()) to use two conditions together